# Cropping image in PHP - html2Canvas duplicates Google Charts text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html2canvas

I've been using `html2Canvas` to convert a Google Chart to an image, so that I could later attach this image to an email. However, `html2Canvas` seems to duplicate the title for my charts, as seen below:

Expected, correct image as shown in the div:

[image: Expected/correct chart, before converting to image]

Converted image, with duplicated title, result from the `javascript` below:

[image: Converted image]

Here is my `javascript` code for converting the div to an image:

```
    var html = $('#chart_div').html();
    html2canvas($('#chart_div'), {
        onrendered: function( canvas ) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
        }
    });
```

I've tried several things to crop the image, including giving `html2canvas` width and height parameters, but that cuts off the bottom and right sides of the image, and not the top. What could I do to either (a) adjust for the duplicate title and crop the top by some number of pixels, or (b) make it so that `html2canvas` renders the text properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same problem, and I've found a solution here:
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/541

In a nutshell, the idea is to replace the `NodeParser.prototype.getChildren` method (lines 2070 to 2075 in the `html2canvas.js` source file for the version `0.5.0-alpha1`), with the following:

```
NodeParser.prototype.getChildren = function(parentContainer) {
    return flatten([].filter.call(parentContainer.node.childNodes, renderableNode).map(function(node) {
        var container = [node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.parentElement.tagName !== "text" ? new TextContainer(node, parentContainer) : new NodeContainer(node, parentContainer)].filter(nonIgnoredElement);
        return node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && container.length && node.tagName !== "TEXTAREA" ? (container[0].isElementVisible() ? container.concat(this.getChildren(container[0])) : []) : container;
    }, this));
};
```

Unless I'm mistaken, this "fix" has not been included in the main release, so it might have side effects, but in my case it did the job.

Hope that helps!